# Grain is not showing in saved/exported file Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, texture

When attempting to export illustrator file that includes heavy grain over black, the grain barely showed in exported image. I have tried exporting as jpeg, svg, for web, for screen, rgb mode, cmyk mode, etc.

The method I used to apply grain was going to Effect > Texture > Grain. My black background had intensity of ~30 with Contrast of ~50 with white text over that has intensity of 100 and Contrast of ~80

Please help.

Comment: Which method/how you applied the grain?

Comment: I updated the post with more detail to answer your question. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Looks like you'll also need to show screenshots of your layer panels and how many layers you have, what color is of text, if text is actual text or expanded shape. I tried with basic settings, and I can see grains very well: https://imgur.com/L8SgiiX

Comment: Do you by any chance have an Illustrator document with very large dimensions which you export to a much smaller size? This might soften the grain.

Comment: That is actually a fairly *subtle* grain. It seems *perceivable* but not really that *visible* upon export. In other words, side by side with an image *not* containing the grain, there's a difference... but it's not immediately recognizable as to what that difference may be (one simply looks more grey at first glance). Of course, all this depends upon image size as well as *which* grain *type* you've chosen. You should also be viewing at 100% in AI - zooming in will make the grain seem more prominent than it actually is.